# How to determine the modifiers for a method or field in Eclipse JDT?

Tags: java, abstract-syntax-tree, visitor-pattern, eclipse-jdt, modifier

I am writing some simple AST visitors for the Eclipse JDT. I have a `MethodVisitor` and `FieldVisitor` class which each extend the `ASTVisitor`. Take the `MethodVisitor` for instance. In that class' `Visit` method (which is an override), I am able to find each of the `MethodDeclaration` nodes. When I have one of those nodes, I want to look at its `Modifiers` to see whether it is `public` or `private` (and perhaps other modifiers as well). There is a method called `getModifiers()`, but it is unclear to me how to use this to determine the type of modifier applied to the particular `MethodDeclaration`. My code is posted below, please let me know if you have any ideas how to proceed.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTVisitor;
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.MethodDeclaration;

public class MethodVisitor extends ASTVisitor {

    private List<MethodDeclaration> methods;

    // Constructor(s)
    public MethodVisitor() {
        this.methods = new ArrayList<MethodDeclaration>();
    }

    /**
     * visit - this overrides the ASTVisitor's visit and allows this
     * class to visit MethodDeclaration nodes in the AST.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean visit(MethodDeclaration node) {
        this.methods.add(node);

            //*** Not sure what to do at this point ***
            int mods = node.getModifiers();

        return super.visit(node);
    }

    /**
     * getMethods - this is an accessor methods to get the methods
     * visited by this class.
     * @return List<MethodDeclaration>
     */
    public List<MethodDeclaration> getMethods() {
        return this.methods;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the documentation states, the result of calling `getModifiers()` is a bit-wise "or" of the relevant [`Modifier`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/Modifier.html) constants. So for example, if you want to find out whether or not the method is `final` you'd use:

```
int modifiers = node.getModifiers();
if (modifiers & Modifier.FINAL != 0) {
    // It's final
}
```

Or you can use the convenience methods in the `Modifier` class:

```
int modifiers = node.getModifiers();
if (Modifier.isFinal(modifiers)) {
    // It's final
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one more helper method `modifiers()` which gives you the list of modifiers your method has. To check whether it is `final` or not, you can directly check in that list.

```
for(Object o : methodDeclarationNode.modifiers()) {  
   if(o.toString().equals("final")) {
      return true;
   }
}
```